# discord.Embed not being treated as embed discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, embed

In first place, sorry for confusing title guys, but i've got no Idea, how to call it more precisely. 
So here's my problem: I have code that's used to get `discord.Embed` object from previous message:

**Creation of Embed:**

```
channel = bot.get_channel(780735930579288115)
embed = discord.Embed(title="December 2020", color=0x6687ff)
embed.set_author(name="New theme voting")
embed.add_field(name="\u200b", value="Nothing Interesting atm", inline=False)
sent = await channel.send("@.everyone We're starting new voting", embed=embed)
config[str(ctx.message.guild.id)]['quiz'] = str(ctx.sent.id)
with open('config.ini', 'w') as configfile:
    config.write(configfile)
```

**Getting Embed object:**

```
config.read("config.ini")
uzenet = await ctx.fetch_message(int(config[str(ctx.message.guild.id)]['quiz']))
embed = uzenet.embeds[0]
await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

**Error:**
And there is this strange error that says that `discord.Embed` object is not `discord.Embed` object(I guess?)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\CoronaBot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/CoronaBot/bot.py", line 476, in newOption
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
AttributeError: type object 'Embed' has no attribute 'from_data'
```

And I have no Idea what else I can do to make python treat it like an `discord.Embed` object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'd need to write `sent.id` instead of `ctx.sent.id` :

```py
channel = bot.get_channel(780735930579288115)

embed = discord.Embed(title="December 2020", color=0x6687ff)
embed.set_author(name="New theme voting")
embed.add_field(name="\u200b", value="Nothing Interesting atm", inline=False)

sent = await channel.send("@.everyone We're starting new voting", embed=embed)

config[str(ctx.message.guild.id)]['quiz'] = str(sent.id) # Here
with open('config.ini', 'w') as configfile:
    config.write(configfile)
```

If you still have any error, please provide more code as that's everything I can find with the sample you gave.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming `ctx.sent.id` is referring to the message id, you should use `ctx.message.id`